# find a word by taking reference of multiple variables in python

Tags: python, file, search, text, nlp

I want to find a word from a text file by using multiple keywords as I have coded for one word as mentioned below: Now I have multiple keywords instead of one word for searching into text file.

Suppose my text file looks as

```
Today's date 25-01-2019
My name is Pratik
My DOB: 1-1-1990
My Date of promotion: 1-1-2019
```

```
import re
with open('abc.txt', encoding= 'utf-8') as abc3:
    for line in abc3: 
        match= re.search(r'date: (\S+)', line)
        if match:
           result = match.group(1)
           print('DATE: '.format(result))
```

I have multiple variables as 'date: ', 'date of promotion', 'DOB: ', ' DATE OF BIRTH: ' instead of one variable in search code line ('date: (\S+)

If any or more of the above variables matches into the text file, how can I code for the same.

```
Expected result
date 25-01-2019
DOB: 1-1-1990
Date of promotion: 1-1-2019
```

Comment: Does each entry (e.g. `DATE`) occur just once? If not, are the individual block delimited? Is the order of entries fixed? And important? Is it safe to assume the input is in fork `ENTRY_NAME: TEXT` and `ENTRY_NAME` must not contain `:`? Do you just want to print? Or actually create some more permanent structure for further processing?

Comment: @ondrej: thanks for reply!!  Date, date of promotion, DOB can be available twice but values are same in whole text file if any of the value match. I dont want in order, from whole list if any of the values are match it should be print. For this value i want to put it in to one table as a result storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do in such cases is to handle case. After you have opened the file convert the string to lowercase. In this specific case this should be good to go.

```
re.findall(r"((?:(?:(?:d|D)ate)|DOB).*)",x)
```

where x is your input string.
I tried it without adjusting case and this should give the answer

```
['date 25-01-2019', 'DOB: 1-1-1990', 'Date of promotion: 1-1-2019']
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I have tried the following code.. ```` with open('.txt', encoding= "utf-8") as abc3        import re            re.findall(r"((?:(?:(?:d|D)ate)DOB).*)", abc3)````      but it shows error "expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Yes you are supposed to convert it to a string. After you do abc3.read(), check if your type is str by writing type(abc3), if not cast it using abc3=str(abc3).